# Como redirecionar o usuário autenticado para uma página específica?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Estou restringindo a pagina de registro do laravel somente para ser mostrada ou acessada depois do login realizado.

Um amigo do grupo stackoverflow me falou que poderia estar fazendo desta forma:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'register', 'showRegistrationForm']]);
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['register', 'showRegistrationForm']]);
}
```

Porém desta forma quando eu realizo o login o sistema me direciona automaticamente para pagina `/register` sendo que o que eu gostaria seria de ser direcionando para o pagina `/dashboard`

Com isto a pagina register seria acessada somente se eu clicasse no link referente a mesma.

Minhas rotas:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::Auth();
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, por padrão o Laravel irá te redirecionar após o login para a raiz do site `/`, que no seu caso é o `'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'`.

Para mudar o caminho do redirecionamento caso o usuário visite uma página exclusiva de visitantes (middleware `guest`), altere esse caminho no middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated`

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/o-caminho-novo-que-eu-quiser');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Não sou muito fã da sua rota `/` apontar para o `AuthController`. Já existe uma rota para isso (`/login`). Talvez ele ser um redirect para `/dashboard` fique melhor. Você pode também juntar seu `Route::group` para um só, pois ambos são iguais (a diferença é que o segundo é gerado pelo `php artisan make:auth`)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    });
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::Auth();
});
```

Comment: Nossa cara muito obrigado fiz desta maneira que você me passou ficou um código muito mais limpo e creio que agora ficou 100%.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: De nada @DouglasSalomão :) Se gostou pode deixar um voto positivo também (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2632/vote-hoje-vote-amanh%c3%a3-vote-sempre-vote-consciente)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema incluindo a seguinte rota no meu routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::Auth();

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
});
```

Não sei se teria alguma maneira melhor porém está ai.

Comment: `Route::Auth();` já cria as rotas de `register`, `login`, etc... Procure não ficar sobrescrevendo suas definições de rotas. Logo logo você vai ficar perdido de tantos lugares que você está aplicando seus middlewares. Vale a pena dar uma boa lida na doc do Laravel sobre [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) e [rotas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing)