# Rotas acessíveis apenas para usuários logados no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, rotas, auth, artisan

Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como criar rotas que podem ser acessadas **apenas** por usuários que estão autenticados, utilizando o `Laravel`?

***Por exemplo***, as rotas que sejam referentes a compartilhar, editar, excluir e ver publicações sejam acessíveis apenas a usuários que estão logados.

Comment: Leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119043/como-redirecionar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-autenticado-para-uma-p%C3%A1gina-espec%C3%ADfica

Comment: Leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154386/routes-laravel-5-3/154413#154413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para isso, você utilizará [Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

**Middlewares**

> Middleware provê um mecanismo para filtragem de requisições HTTP na
>   sua aplicação. Por exemplo, o Laravel inclui um middleware que
>   verifica se o usuário da sua aplicação está autenticado. Se o usuário
>   não estiver autenticado, o middleware will redirecionará o usuário
>   para a página de login. Entretanto, se o usuário estiver autenticado,
>   o middleware permitirá a requisição seguir adiante na sua aplicação.

**Auth Middleware**

O Laravel já vem com algums middlewares pra você utilizar, e um deles é o `auth`. Você pode aplicar este middleware de várias formas.

**[Rota Específica](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)**

Atribuindo o middleware a rota via método fluente.

```
Route::get('admin/posts/create', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

**[Grupo de Rotas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-middleware)**

Atribuindo o middleware a um grupo de rotas.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/posts/create', function () {});
    Route::get('admin/user/profile', function () {});
});
```

**[Via Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controller-middleware)**

Você pode atribuir direto no controller também.

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Nesse caso o middleware auth será aplicado a todos os métodos
        $this->middleware('auth');

        // mas, você pode fazer uso dos métodos fluentes: only e except
        // ex.: $this->middleware('auth')->only(['create', 'store']);
        // ex.: $this->middleware('auth')->except('index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção é agrupar as rotas que você quer proteger, dessa forma:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
     Route::get('sua_url', function());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso você pode usar os [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) do Laravel, que são basicamente funções executadas antes ou depois da rota que podem afetar a execução de uma controller / action.

Um exemplo de Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Perform action

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Um exemplo de uma rota com um Middleware:

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    // Seu código
})->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os  [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) do laravel, conforme as respostas anteriores e "reforçar" em seu código HTML, como por exemplo, somente o usuário indicado como adm acesse.

Outra dica importante, é sempre bom vc prevenir que alguém acesse o histórico da página após o usuário deslogar/sair.

Com o Middleware também é possível fazer isso:
Um exemplo:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PreventBackHistory
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $headers = [
        'Cache-Control' => 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma','no-cache',
        'Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
        ];

        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->headers->set($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```